# Force Trailling slash and problem with pop up

Tags: .htaccess

Hi I have found this code about the trailling slash and it works perfect.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(html|jpg|png|gif)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

My problem is that it doesn't work properly the add to cart button. 
In my site when i push the add to cart then shows a pop up and inside the popup shows 2 buttons. "Continue Shopping" and "View cart and checkout".

Now when i click the add to cart it shows the pop up but instead of the buttons it shows the message "error".

Can someone help me ?

regards

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.
I removed all the above code and i have add the bellow.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

it works properly, adds the trailling slash and everything work like it should.

Comment: If you think your answer best answers your question please accept it when you'll be able to.